# Root cause analysis using Machine Learning or NN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, lstm, pattern-recognition

I am trying to build a predictive model that will analyze pattern from a snapshot file (log) and give the root cause analysis of the file i.e the class to which the pattern in the logs belongs to.

I have a lift company data. Whenever an error occurs in the lift for eg. the shaft door was opened, a snapshot or log file is generated containing the information about the status of the various switches in the lift. These form a pattern inside the snapshot file, for example each use case(Shaft Door opened) will have a unique pattern. I want to apply Machine learning to try and learn the pattern automatically and predict the output class.

The problem I am facing is in the previous machine learning tasks I faced each observation was a unique example for eg in Loan prediction dataset each row was one observation. But in this case the entire snapshot is one example containing approx 23k rows. How can I apply machine learning in this task. How to consider one snapshot consisting of 23k rows to be one observation with Class label and feed it to the algorithm?.

Also how can I use NN for such tasks as I have come to know that LSTM is good for sequence pattern analysis. My dataset consists of 20 snapshots each of 2 use cases consisting about 61 columns or features. The result I want is whenever i give a snapshot file to the model it should be able to predict the class to which the error in the snapshot file belongs to. (not forgetting the snapshot file itself contains 23k rows)

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome Errol! 
I'm curious as to how this dataset looks like. Will it be feasible for you to provide link for community to at least view 1 row of this data? Recommendation for pattern analysis with RNN, etc will get easier then, IMO.

Comment: If the pattern of each error is known and unique, machine learning is not needed. Just a program that looks for the pattern which would give 100% accuracy.

Comment: @Craig no the pattern is not known before hand. We only know that if an error occurs it will have a unique pattern but the pattern is not known.@Random Nerd

Comment: @Random Nerd here is the link to one of the log file [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eKigli61QaoDYgPtPVWtC2V4qoeU3vrk). Note that this is one snapshot file belonging to class A. In this file I have labelled every observation as Class A but i want a strategy to give the entire file to the algorithm and the lable as Calss A for it to learn the pattern from it automatically.

Comment: @RandomNerd shared the link above.